# Pass Param to report from LWC in Community

Tags: lightning-web-components, reporting, customer-portal

I want to redirect community users to a standard report and pass a parameter when a URL is clicked. This URL is on a LWC and based on the record where the hyperlink is clicked, that record's name is passed.

I tried below approach but didn't work,

```
navigateToAccReport(event) {
      event.stopPropagation();
      this[NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl]({
        type: 'standard__recordPage',
        attributes: {
          recordId: '00O************',
          actionName: 'view'
        },
        state : {
                fv2: this.accName
            }
    
      }).then(url => { window.open(url) });
    }
```

Its redirecting but I don't see the parameter value populated  in the report. My filter still shows blank. When I manually paste the URL in salesforce internally it works but doesn't work within the portal. Links below,

Salesforce Internal URL: `https://mydomain.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Report/00O************/view?fv2="Account Name"`

Community url:

```
https://mysite.sandbox.my.site.com/communityname/s/report/00O************/report-name?fv2="Account Name"
```

Need inputs.